# I have spring boot services. i have to configure 2nd service database and Respository class to first service.How to achieve it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

2nd Service Repository and DB Connection

```
@Repository
public interface AuthUserRepository extends CrudRepository<AuthUserModel, String>  {
}

spring.datasource.driver.class =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url =${AUTH_DB_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fiu_auth_db}
spring.datasource.username =${AUTH_DB_USERNAME:root}
spring.datasource.password =${AUTH_DB_PASSWORD:root}
```

1st Service Configuration Class and DB Connection

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

}

spring.datasource.driver.class =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url =${AUTH_DB_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fiu_user_db}
spring.datasource.username =${AUTH_DB_USERNAME:root}
spring.datasource.password =${AUTH_DB_PASSWORD:root}
```

I have Tried adding second database in Configuration file.But iam unable to add. how can i add second database in 1st service(in my case user service). 2nd service is Auth Service. Can access Auth Repository and Database without an entity in User service?